# r if statement "unexpected ')'

Tags: r, if-statement

I'm pretty new to r and can't get this if statement to work

```
if(y==67){
  lowermort = 1
} else{
  lowermort = sum(tpxoverilower[1:(y-67)]) + 1 )
}
```

I get this error

```
Error: unexpected ')' in:
"} else{
  lowermort = sum(tpxoverilower[1:(y-67)]) + 1 )"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an extra end parentheses at the end of the statement

```
lowermort = sum(tpxoverilower[1:(y-67)]) + 1 )
```

it should be

```
lowermort = sum(tpxoverilower[1:(y-67)]) + 1
```

When you're new to r, always make sure to double check that your parentheses, equals signs, etc are all in the right place - it will cause a lot of errors starting out. The `"unexpected X"` error derives from exactly this.